# Function in type constraint

Tags: haskell

Checking type of `(Just (+2)) <*> (Just (+2))`
I have found it has constraint `Num (a -> a)`, which is confusing to what `Num (a -> a)` should mean here

```
(Just (+2)) <*> (Just (+2)) :: (Num a, Num (a -> a)) => Maybe (a -> a)
```

Comment: It means it thinks that a function `a -> a` should be an instance of `Num`, this because `Just (+2) <*> Just (+2)` is equivalent to `Just ((+2)+2)`, and thus it assumes that `+2`, a function thus, should be a number type in order to be a parameter to add.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so assuming `Just ((+x)+y)` `Num (a -> a)` is happening because  `+y` can only accept numbers?

Comment: `(+)` has type `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, so the operands should be of a type that is an instance of `Num`.

Comment: I see, and its understandable why ghci gives error if I don't prepend :t, thank you

Comment: because it does not know about any type `a -> a` that is an instance of `Num`, nor are there defaulting rules for that (since well, there is no instance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us analyze the types first. `Just (+2)` has type `Just (+2) :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)`, and `(<*>)` has type [**`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (c -> d) -> f c -> f d`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-) .

If we thus construct an expression `(<*>) (Just (+2)) (Just (+2))`, then the type is equivalent to:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (c -> d)     -> f c            -> f d
Just (+2) :: Num a =>     Maybe (a -> a)
Just (+2) :: Num b =>                       Maybe (b -> b)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
f ~ Maybe, a ~ c ~ d, c ~ (b -> b)
```

It thus means that the applicative type is `Maybe`, and that `a`, `c` and `d` are the same type, and that `c` is equivalent to `(b -> b)`. Since there is a type constraint `Num a`, and `a ~ c`, it means that the type contraint also holds for `c`, and thus that `Num b => (b -> b)` needs to be an instance of the `Num` typeclass. The result of this type is thus:

```
(<*>) (Just (+2)) (Just (+2)) :: Num b => Maybe (b -> b)
```

This makes sense, since the outcome of `Just (+2) <*> Just (+2)` will be `Just ((+2) + 2)`, and since `(+)` has type [**`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-), and therefore it thus expects that the first operand `(+2)` which is a function, should be of a type that is an instance of `Num`.